UpdateFromQuery - handling nullable db columns
Does N.EntityFramework.Extensions correctly handle db nullable columns?
For example. There is a table MyTable with 2 nullable nvarchar columns: col1, col2.
Both columns has values in db filled (not null):
id  col1 col2
-------------
1    A    B
2    C    D

This is my code:
DbContext.MyTable
         .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
         .UpdateFromQuery(x => new MyTable { col1 = null });

So the questions overall: how does UpdateFromQuery determine which columns need to be updated to NULL and which is just not specified and should be skipped? Would the result of query above will set col1 to NULL and leave col2="B"? Because in C# object both fields are NULL (default string value).
Thanks

For the last part, isn't is easier to just check the result of the command?

It is done through reflection. To begin with, UpdateFromQuery accepts Expression. Expression allows to obtain some extra metadata related to it.
public static int UpdateFromQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> querable, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateExpression)

If you dig down into the source code, you can find other code this method invokes. Sources
expression.Body as MemberInitExpression and then memberInitExpression.Bindings then only contains fields that were set to some value in the passed expression. This way library knows that you have set value to col1 but not col2, and converts this "knowledge" to SQL
    internal static string ToSqlUpdateSetExpression<T>(this Expression<T> expression, string tableName)
    {
        List<string> setValues = new List<string>();
        var memberInitExpression = expression.Body as MemberInitExpression;
        foreach (var binding in memberInitExpression.Bindings)
        {
            string expValue = GetExpressionValueAsString(binding);
            expValue = expValue.Replace(string.Format("{0}.", expression.Parameters.First().Name),
                string.Format("{0}.", tableName));
            setValues.Add(string.Format("{0}.[{1}]={2}", tableName, binding.Member.Name, expValue));
        }
        return string.Join(",", setValues);
    }


thank you; did I understand correctly? If some tbl has 3 nullable fields: col1, col2, col3; and I need to set col1="1", col2=NULL and leave col3 without changes I could do next:
DbContext.Table1.Where(x=>x.Id=1).UpdateFromQuery(x=>new Table1 { col1="1", col2=nulll });

Yes, it should work exactly this way
